# Slice list where index values are strings?

Tags: python, list, int, concatenation, slice

I have loaded a black and white image as a numpy array. The array shape is equal to the pixels in the image. I want to extract certain ranges of pixel values, for instance,

```
numpy_array_to_slice[160:300,28:43]
```

etc etc, but I don't want to hardcode the index numbers. Rather, I want to load the index values from a list of values. For instance, I have a list of index values like:

```
listofindexvalues = [['160:300,28:43'],['160:300,40:55'],['160:300,28:43']]
```

So effectively I want something like:

```
numpy_array_to_slice[listofindexvalues[0]]
```

which would take the place of:

```
numpy_array_to_slice['160:300,28:43']
```

I've tried a variety of things which haven't worked like:

```
first,second = str(index_list[19]).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','').split(':')  ##for just one side of an index value, such as 28:59
```

and trying to pass that like so:

```
numpy_array_to_slice[int(first)+':'+int(second]
```

but that doesn't work because I can't concatenate those values. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slicing is *syntax*, not a string. See the [*Slicings* expressions reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings):

> The semantics for a slicing are as follows. The primary is indexed (using the same `__getitem__()` method as normal subscription) with a key that is constructed from the slice list, as follows. **If the slice list contains at least one comma, the key is a tuple containing the conversion of the slice items**; otherwise, the conversion of the lone slice item is the key. The conversion of a slice item that is an expression is that expression. **The conversion of a proper slice is a `slice` object (see section [The standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#types)) whose `start`, `stop` and `step` attributes are the values of the expressions given as lower bound, upper bound and stride, respectively, substituting `None` for missing expressions.**

Bold emphasis mine.

You can bypass this conversion (from slice syntax to `slice()` objects) by creating `slice()` objects directly; you can put them in tuples if need be.

So

```
numpy_array_to_slice[160:300,28:43]
```

is equivalent to

```
box = slice(160, 300), slice(28, 43)
numpy_array_to_slice[box]
```

I've omitted the `step` argument; it defaults to `None` when omitted.

Extending this to your list would be:

```
listofindexvalues = [
    (slice(160, 300), slice(28, 43)),
    (slice(160, 300), slice(40, 55)),
    (slice(160, 300), slice(28, 43))
]

for box in listofindexvalues:
    sliced_array = numpy_array_to_slice[box]
```

Comment: Even if I read the documentation I'm not sure i would have understood it that easily. Thanks again, that's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a list of `slice` instances (or tuples thereof), not strings.

Here's an example.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> listofindexvalues = [(slice(1, 6), slice(3, 4))]
>>> a = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
>>> a[listofindexvalues[0]]
array([[13],
       [23],
       [33],
       [43],
       [53]])
```

`a[listofindexvalues[0]]` is equivalent to `a[1:6, 3:4]` in this case.

```
>>> a[1:6, 3:4]
array([[13],
       [23],
       [33],
       [43],
       [53]])
```